# Determine on which physical processor my code is currently running

Tags: windows, processor

Is there a Windows API or any way to determine on which physical processor/core my current thread runs? I don't need that information. I'm just curious.

I'm not interested in the processors the thread is allowed to run on. I would like to know on exactly which one it currently runs. I know that the threads switch pretty fast from one to another...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads will often switch from processor to processor, so it's kind of meaningless, but you can use [`GetCurrentProcessorNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683181(VS.85).aspx).

As others have said, you can use `GetProcessAffinityMask` or `GetThreadIdealProcessor`, but those will only work if you've already set an affinity mask or ideal processor for the thread.

Comment: Didn't think this was possible, but turns out that it is - edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Nice, didn't realise that was possible.

Comment: I could do some cool useless things with that information like statistics or some kind of visualization ;) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can query the processor affinity with [GetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683213(VS.85).aspx). If you haven't set processor affinity, I'm unsure how useful the result will be though, as the thread can flit between processors.

Answer (score 2):

For controlling which processor your process or thread runs on using the Windows API you can use [SetThreadAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686247(VS.85).aspx) or [SetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223(VS.85).aspx).

These work by setting bits in a bit mask, where each bit represents a processor your thread or process can be scheduled for:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetProcessAffinityMask(
  __in  HANDLE hProcess,
  __in  DWORD_PTR dwProcessAffinityMask
);
```

Call [GetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683213(VS.85).aspx) to discover which processors are available for use in these calls.